# How to fix a Popup window on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, popup

Hi in my application I want to change the look and feel of the caller screen of the device, now (I may be wrong) the only way to do that is to call a popup window over the default android caller screen because you cannot change it.

My popup window comes up when the user hit dial but then it is replaced by the default caller screen, my popup goes behind the default caller screen.

How can I fix my popup window on the screen so that it is not replaced by any other screen.

My DialerFragment.java:

```
package com.heroicjokester.android.haid;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

/**
 * Created by Ripcord on 01-Apr-16.
 */
public class DialerFragment extends Fragment {
private EditText mPhoneField;
private Button mDialButton;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private PopupWindow mPopupWindow;

//Requesting Permissions on Runtime.
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS=0;

private void InitiateCall(){
    int hasCallPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (hasCallPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults ){
   switch (requestCode){
       case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
           if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               //YAY! PERMISSION GRANTED
               InitiateCall();
           }else{
               //GD! PERMISSION DENIED
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
            break;
       default:
           super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

   }
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialer,container,false);

    mPhoneField=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_pno);
    mDialButton=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dial_button);
    mLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.popup_linearlayout);

    mDialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mPhoneField != null && (mPhoneField.getText().length() == 10 || mPhoneField.getText().length() == 11)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + mPhoneField.getText())));
                } else if (mPhoneField != null && mPhoneField.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_number_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (mPhoneField != null && mPhoneField.getText().length() < 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.wrong_number_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("DialerAppActivity", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);//Runtime error will be logged
            }

            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialer_popup, null);

            mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, false);
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mLinearLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

            container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.hit_it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;

                }
            });

        }
    });

    InitiateCall();

    return v;


}


}
```

Comment: your problem is Intent.ACTION_CALL. That will go another app's activity... that's why you pop up doesn't work

Comment: So is there any way around it? 
There are applications which are doing this, how did they manage to do that?